# evdev events not showing up in libinput or X11

Tags: linux, x11, drivers, devices, libinput

Some background: I'm using a VEIKK A50 graphics tablet with a custom patched version of [this driver](https://github.com/jlam55555/veikk-linux-driver) to add button support. The tablet registers 3 evdev devices upon being plugged in - pen events come through one of them, button events come through the second and I'm assuming the third is used for the gesture pad, which I've not got working yet.

The button events are detected just fine using `evtest`:

```
$ evtest /dev/input/event7
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x2feb product 0x3 version 0x100
Input device name: "VEIKK A50 Pen"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 256 (BTN_0)
    Event code 257 (BTN_1)
    Event code 258 (BTN_2)
    Event code 259 (BTN_3)
    Event code 260 (BTN_4)
    Event code 261 (BTN_5)
    Event code 262 (BTN_6)
    Event code 263 (BTN_7)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 331 (BTN_STYLUS)
    Event code 332 (BTN_STYLUS2)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    32768
      Resolution       1
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    32768
      Resolution       1
    Event code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     8192
Properties:
  Property type 0 (INPUT_PROP_POINTER)
  Property type 1 (INPUT_PROP_DIRECT)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1593877860.725627, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 256 (BTN_0), value 1
Event: time 1593877860.725627, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877860.821631, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 256 (BTN_0), value 0
Event: time 1593877860.821631, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877861.053666, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 257 (BTN_1), value 1
Event: time 1593877861.053666, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877861.133790, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 257 (BTN_1), value 0
Event: time 1593877861.133790, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877861.477718, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 258 (BTN_2), value 1
Event: time 1593877861.477718, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877861.549708, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 258 (BTN_2), value 0
Event: time 1593877861.549708, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877861.918267, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 259 (BTN_3), value 1
Event: time 1593877861.918267, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877861.990011, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 259 (BTN_3), value 0
Event: time 1593877861.990011, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877862.766219, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 260 (BTN_4), value 1
Event: time 1593877862.766219, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877862.885867, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 260 (BTN_4), value 0
Event: time 1593877862.885867, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877863.301937, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 261 (BTN_5), value 1
Event: time 1593877863.301937, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877863.397949, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 261 (BTN_5), value 0
Event: time 1593877863.397949, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877864.694091, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 262 (BTN_6), value 1
Event: time 1593877864.694091, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877864.830257, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 262 (BTN_6), value 0
Event: time 1593877864.830257, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877865.182508, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 263 (BTN_7), value 1
Event: time 1593877865.182508, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1593877865.278161, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 263 (BTN_7), value 0
Event: time 1593877865.278161, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

However, when using `libinput debug-events` or `xev`, nothing happens when any button is pressed. I have added a custom X11 config file to force the tablet through evdev directly rather than going through libinput, and `xev` detects nothing despite this.

I have also tried changing the buttons in the driver code to have them output known-working events such as BTN_STYLUS (sent from `/dev/input/event6` when one of the two stylus buttons is pressed) or KEY_A. Neither of these were detected by libinput or xev.

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see if the X server registers `/dev/input/event6` as event source. If not, there should be some hints what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt, checking the log helped. Turns out I hadn't installed xf86-input-evdev so it was falling back to libinput. Still not sure why libinput isn't detecting the key events, but it works now so I don't care :) If you wanna post an answer so I can accept it, feel free

Comment: You figured it out, you post the answer. You can accept your own answer.